# Trying to add cell from existing tableview to a new tableview when a button is pressed (Add to favorites button)

Tags: objective-c, view, uitableview, xcode4.5

I'm attempting to add a "Favorites" star to an existing tableview list. The star is a button, and exists inside of every cell. When the star is pressed, I want to add the cell it's contained inside to a new tableview, thus creating a list of favorites.

***E.g. if button is pressed, add cell to favoritesTableView.***

There's next to no documentation online for this (that I can see), but here's what I have so far.

Note: searchResults = Favorited Items*

**TableView.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 


        cell = [[[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;



        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
       NSLog(@"Using the search results");

        cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);





    } else {
        NSLog(@"Using the FULL LIST!!");
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
         cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
         cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

    }


    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"StrainTableCell"];
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

return cell;


}


- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"StrainTableCell"];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i know I'm going to get a comment by some admin that this isn't a answer" but a much easier way would be reloading your table view with the array of favorites information after user decides they want to see favorites. Other then that what issues are you having with this and i will further re-edit my answer to help you, are you simply not getting any results at all?

adding answer below:

Looks like for your situation this fits your needs

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
if (indexPath != nil)
{
[self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}
```

this is how the code is on http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/

and the code ends by calling

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

though you could replace that or add your needed code inside that method. Your needed code would be to create a NSMutablearray I'm assuming you know how if you're not that familiar with it make sure you test it out by running a nslog after adding something to it. Once you have your NSMutablearray for favorites you would add something like...

```
[myFavoritesArray addobject:[myOriginalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath]];
```

I'm not sure if you are changing views between original table and favorites table but if they are practically the same then you could just reload the table with the press of a button, unless you wan't the animation of switching views of course depending on how navigation is setup. Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi! I'm just trying to figure out how to create the array of favorites. For example, once a user sees the full list of cafes, once the user clicks on the "star" button to favorite, what kind of code can I use to tell the app to save this favorite, and then load it to the favourites table? Thank you!

Comment: Amazing Reference. Okay, so take a look at my updated code above (the .m file). For some reason after implementing this, the simulator throws me a SIGBRT error under my else statement for this line: cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];

Comment: oh...it's the object for key part that you have... that's a nsdictionary type function not a nsmutablearray but i know what you are trying to do here..i just need a second to look at the code again

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This has been driving me nuts. Standing by... :)

Comment: I'm getting lost and trying to talk within stack overflow comments is killing me...can you email me your two tableview classes IPhoneHungry@yahoo.com and ill try and save you some time and frustration

Comment: what you want is your custom cell to be a class with properties like label text, description text, etc.... then you will create custom cell objects with their own strings and images whatever they may be and add then to one array and in the end you will be able to call myCurrentCell = [myAwesomeArrayOfCustomCells objectAtIndex:indexPath].thisCellsTextLabel;